# Как сделать такую галерею (flexbox)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: НУжно сделать похожее расположение карточек в галерее]

Проблема с выравниванием, когда делаю новый ряд(2), блоки выравниваются по линии, а нужно чтобы под каждым отдельным блоком. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте контейнеру с `display: flex` свойство `flex-flow: column wrap` — таким образом потомки будут располагаться по оси Y, а не X, и будут переноситься. Также добавьте ему ограничение по высоте. Обратите внимание на порядок блоков.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 700px;
}

.block {
  width: 180px;
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block--1 {
  height: 100px;
}

.block--2 {
  height: 150px;
}

.block--3 {
  height: 170px;
}

.block--4 {
  height: 120px;
}

.block--5 {
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="block block--2">1</div>
  <div class="block block--1">2</div>
  <div class="block block--4">3</div>
  <div class="block block--3">4</div>
  <div class="block block--5">5</div>
  <div class="block block--1">6</div>
  <div class="block block--4">7</div>
  <div class="block block--3">8</div>
  <div class="block block--2">9</div>
  <div class="block block--5">10</div>
  <div class="block block--1">11</div>
</div>
```